# Do I need to initialize the 'i' variable in a for loop?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, gas

Do I need to explicitly initialize the 'i' variable in a for loop? Since `i` is a `uint` and its default value is `0`, why should I spend gas in a MSTORE operation to initialize the variable with `0`? The same question applies to `result`.

```
function sum10() external pure returns (uint256) {
    uint256 result;
    for(uint256 i; i< 10; i++){
       result += i;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This kind of things are simply easiest to try out in something like Remix.

I tried all three variants: as-is, explicitly setting `i` and explicitly setting `result` . The first two cost the same (25315), and the last one costs 25323.

Honestly, I'm really not sure why it's like this.